# cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. eclipse indigo

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I was installing adb and found an error like this.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
  Missing requirement: Android Traceview 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.7.0' but it could not be found

What should I do? Anyone please help..

Comment: Looks like your eclipse is too old. Try upgrading to Kelper?

Comment: I have tried many times. Tried kepler, juno etc, but unable to find android packages inside it. Thats why i go for indigo.

Answer (score 0):

Please download latest version of eclipse and try. it will work.
i have done same when i had same type of issue.